# I'm making a Discord bot and I ran into an Unexpected Token Error

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, discord

Here's the code I put in

```
 const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const TOKEN = 'insert token here'

bot.on('message', function(message) {
    if(message.content == "hello") {
        message.reply('Hey what up?');
    }
    ;

    bot.login(TOKEN);
    }
)
```

And here's the error I got

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:267:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:319:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:733:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:300:19)
```

I'm sorry if this is a really dumb question, I'm basically a newbie when it comes to coding this sort of stuff and coding in general for that matter.

(Just to note I’m using visual studio code and node.js)

Comment: Where is the token?

Comment: Note `SyntaxError:`. Although there is "unexpected token" in the error message, it's unlikely related to a service token.

Comment: You should format your code and check it. Is this exactly the code you have made?

Comment: I checked your code in an AST viewer and see nothing wrong with it.  The code in the question will not exhibit the indicated syntax error.

Comment: I believe you need a semicolon at the end there as you are not defining the function `bot.on` but rather calling it

Comment: @casualcoder The missing semicolon wouldn't cause the indicated syntax error.  He isn't getting a `Missing Semicolon Before Statement` error.

Comment: Is the error a build output? Based on the stack trace, looks like a CommonJS module loader (webpack?) is erroring. Assuming this is webpack, would you be open to editing your question to add your webpack.config.js?

Comment: Edited. @stealththeninja

Comment: Maybe I’m dense but the edit still leaves me wondering where the error happens. Is it during a build (compile) step, is it at runtime? How would I recreate the minimal conditions to make this error happen?

Comment: Really the only thing I can think of that went wrong was I didn’t install some external software where the node.js recommended me to download while I was installing it. And yes, it was in the compile step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bot.login(TOKEN);` needs to be outside of your message event handler. Additionally, your code formatting is incorrect. Here is corrected code that should work for you:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const TOKEN = 'your_token'

bot.on('message', function(message) {
    if(message.content == "hello") {
        message.reply('Hey what up?');
    }
});

bot.login(TOKEN);
```